# How to limit amount of CoroutineWorkers working at the same time

Tags: android, kotlin, parallel-processing, android-workmanager, coroutineworker

I've created simple test app to run multiple CoroutineWorkers in the background:

```
class Work(context: Context, workerParameters: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker(context, workerParameters) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        Log.d("bagins", "Work ${this.tags.first()} started")
        runBlocking {
            delay(5000)
        }
        Log.d("bagins", "Work ${this.tags.first()} finished")
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

I launch them with
`workManager.enqueue(workers)`

But I don't want all of them to working simultaneously. I want max 2 to be executed at the same time.

Based on examples found I udpated AndroidManifest.xml by adding:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
    tools:node="remove">
</provider>
```

And Application class to this:

```
class App : Application(), Configuration.Provider {
    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration(): Configuration {
        val executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)
        return Configuration.Builder().setExecutor(executor).build()
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        WorkManager.initialize(this, workManagerConfiguration)
    }
}
```

If I execute workManager.enqueue multiple (10) times it is executing the CoroutineWorkers simultaneously. I want them to be executed max 2 parallel, and if new added to the queue, I want this rule to still work.

Comment: Are you using Kotlin?

Comment: @LajosArpad yes

Comment: "But I don't want all of them to working simultaneously. I want max 2 to be executed at the same time." - can you explain why? 2 seems like an oddly specific number. What is okay at 2 that absolutely cannot work at 3?

Comment: @ianhanniballake If no further information is provided about why the limitation is 2, we can take it as an example. The problem is probably that the many coroutines are eating up all the resources and there is a need to reduce the load by limiting the maximum nunmber of coroutines that may run at a specific time.

Comment: @LajosArpad - resourcing starvation across multiple coroutines would be a very different problem with a _very_ different solution, hence why I am asking.

Comment: @ianhanniballake - number is just an example. I'm surprised that limiting size of threadpool (especially that we can configure it) doesn't work. Anyway I'm trying to workaround other issue: limitations to starting foreground Workers from background service in Android 13. I launched those workers manually one by one. But now setForeground causes ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException

Comment: Ha! I found why it fails. Setting Executor works but only if my Work class extends Worker. In this case it runs max 2. But when extends CoroutineWorker it does not. I need to find a way to set the same limitations for CoroutineWorker!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should use non-suspend worker version extending from Worker instead of CoRoutineWorker. Then use *runBlocking* to wait for suspend method to finish the work.

```
  override fun doWork(): Result  = runBlocking{
          try{
              //your long running code
              Result.success()
          }catch (ie:InterruptedException){
              Result.retry()
          }
        }
    }
```

*runBlocking* may throw InterruptedException. So you need to catch it and return the Resutl.retry.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal, you can use a [Semaphore](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-semaphore/), like

```
// This is example to explain the API for semaphore

fun main() {
  // Creates semaphore with 10 permits
  val semaphore = Semaphore(permits = 10)
  
  // Acquires a permit from this semaphore, suspending until one is available. 
  // All suspending acquirers are processed in first-in-first-out (FIFO) order
  semaphore.acquire() 
  
  // Releases a permit, returning it into this semaphore. 
  // Resumes the first suspending acquirer if there is one at the point of invocation
  semaphore.release()
}
```

Another example:

```
fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.map(
    concurrency: Int,
    transform: (T) -> R
): List<R> = runBlocking {
    // Create semaphore with permit specified as `concurrency`
    val semaphore = Semaphore(concurrency)
   
    map { item ->
        // Before processing each item, acquire the semaphore permit
        // This will be suspended until permit is available.
        semaphore.acquire()
        
        async(Dispatchers.Default) {
            try {
                transform(item)
            } finally {
                // After processing (or failure), release a semaphore permit
                semaphore.release()
            }
        }
    }.awaitAll()
}

fun doSomething(users: List<User>) {
    // Concurrently 5 users will be processed
    users.map(concurrency = 5) { user -> user.toSomething() /* `toSomething()` is heavy method */ }
}
```

Both examples were taken from [here](https://blog.shreyaspatil.dev/leveraging-the-semaphore-concept-in-coroutines-to-limit-the-parallelism), I strongly recommend reading the article.